# Properties and inheriting from instances

Tags: python, oop, properties

So I usually don't use OOP and apparently I don't understand it as well as I thought I did.

Suppose I have a class for a (geographic) State:

```
class State(object):
    @property
    def population(self):
        return self._population
    @population.setter
    def population(self,value):
        if value < 0:
            raise ValueError("Population must not be negative")
        else:
            self._population = value
```

and a virtually identical (just at the moment) class for a Town:

```
class Town(State):
    @property
    def population(self):
        return self._population
    @population.setter
    def population(self,value):
        if value < 0:
            raise ValueError("Population must not be negative")
        else:
            self._population = value
```

Now suppose I instantiate a State and give it a specific population. How would I create an instance of a Town that inherits that State instance's population? (Temporarily, I suppose - it's just an example.) Or should I be using composition rather than inheritance?

The way I'm currently thinking of it, this should work:

```
s = State()

s.population = 10

t = Town(s)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-141-00f052d998f0> in <module>()
----> 1 t = Town(s)

TypeError: object.__new__() takes no parameters
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would not say that a Town *is a* State(unless you live in Singapore or Hong Kong!).  But you would say that a State *has a* Town.  That indicates composition.

Note that a State doesn't even have a population attribute by default.  So inheriting from State does not give Town any attributes:

```
class State(object):
    @property
    def population(self):
        return self._population
    @population.setter
    def population(self,value):
        if value < 0:
            raise ValueError("Population must not be negative")
        else:
            self._population = value

s = State()
print s.population

--output:--
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 13, in <module>
    print s.population
  File "1.py", line 4, in population
    return self._population
AttributeError: 'State' object has no attribute '_population'
```

So when you say:

> Now suppose I instantiate a State and give it a specific population.
>   How would I create an instance of a Town that inherits that State
>   instance's population?

...that doesn't make any sense because the Town class has no knowledge of any instances of State.  The obvious answer to giving a Town instance the same population as a State instance is to do this:

```
class State(object):
    @property
    def population(self):
        return self._population
    @population.setter
    def population(self,value):
        if value < 0:
            raise ValueError("Population must not be negative")
        else:
            self._population = value

class Town(object):
    def __init__(self, population):
        self._population = population

    @property
    def population(self):
        return self._population

s = State()
s.population = 30
print s.population

t = Town(s.population)
print t.population
```

Using composition, you could do something like this:

```
class State(object):
    def __init__(self, name, *towns):
        self.name = name
        self.towns = towns 

    @property
    def population(self):
        total = 0
        for town in self.towns:
            total += town.population
        return total

class Town(object):
    def __init__(self, name, population):
        self._population = population

    @property
    def population(self):
        return self._population

    @population.setter
    def population(self,value):
        if value < 0:
            raise ValueError("Population must not be negative")
        else:
            self._population = value

detroit = Town("Detroit", 40)
lansing = Town("Lansing", 100)
detroit.population -= 10
print detroit.population
print lansing.population

s = State("Michigan", detroit, lansing)
print s.population

--output:--
30
100
130
```

Comment: A very thorough answer -- thank you! I had suspected composition was the way to go, but I wasn't seeing the utility of building from the bottom up, as you did.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have it written right now, you have described a Town as being a State, while a State is not necessarily a town. That is, a Town by default behaves exactly like a State unless otherwise specified.

If you want to pass a State into the Town initializer, then you need to create a function something like the following:

```
class Town(State):
    def __init__(self, state):
        self._population = state._population
```

After that, you should not get the `TypeError` from your example, and it would behave how you might expect.